# chef 11: any way to turn attributes into a ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, attributes, chef-infra

I'm generating a config for my service in chef attributes. However, at some point, I need to turn the attribute mash into a simple ruby hash. This used to work fine in Chef 10:

```
node.myapp.config.to_hash
```

However, starting with Chef 11, this does not work. Only the top-level of the attribute is converted to a hash, with then nested values remaining immutable mash objects. Modifying them leads to errors like this:

> Chef::Exceptions::ImmutableAttributeModification
>   ------------------------------------------------ Node attributes are read-only when you do not specify which precedence level to set. To
>   set an attribute use code like `node.default["key"] = "value"'

I've tried a bunch of ways to get around this issue which do not work:

```
node.myapp.config.dup.to_hash
JSON.parse(node.myapp.config.to_json)
```

The json parsing hack, which seems like it should work great, results in:

```
JSON::ParserError
unexpected token at '"#<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x000000020eee88>"'
```

Is there any actual reliable way, short of including a nested parsing function in each cookbook, to convert attributes to a simple, ordinary, good old ruby hash?

Comment: i don't need it -- i could quit any time i want! but seriously, i'm building a config file out of lots of disparate attributes, and i need to modify them before writing them into the config file. it's really helpful to convert the attributes into a hash, mutate them, and then use the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed for a long time now:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'chef/node'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> node = Chef::Node.new
[....]
[3] pry(main)> node.default["fizz"]["buzz"] = { "foo" => [ { "bar" => "baz" } ] }
=> {"foo"=>[{"bar"=>"baz"}]}
[4] pry(main)> buzz = node["fizz"]["buzz"].to_hash
=> {"foo"=>[{"bar"=>"baz"}]}
[5] pry(main)> buzz.class
=> Hash
[6] pry(main)> buzz["foo"].class
=> Array
[7] pry(main)> buzz["foo"][0].class
=> Hash
[8] pry(main)>
```

Probably fixed sometime in or around Chef 12.x or Chef 13.x, it is certainly no longer an issue in Chef 15.x/16.x/17.x

Answer (score 11):

after a resounding lack of answers both here and on the opscode chef mailing list, i ended up using the following hack:

```
class Chef
  class Node
   class ImmutableMash
      def to_hash
        h = {}
        self.each do |k,v|
          if v.respond_to?('to_hash')
            h[k] = v.to_hash
          else
            h[k] = v
          end
        end
        return h
      end
    end
  end
end
```

i put this into the libraries dir in my cookbook; now i can use attribute.to_hash in both chef 10 (which already worked properly and which is unaffected by this monkey-patch) and chef 11. i've also reported this as a bug to opscode:

<s>if you don't want to have to monkey-patch your chef, speak up on this issue:
[http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3857](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409231528/http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3857)</s>

**Update:** monkey-patch ticket was marked closed by [these](https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/670) [PRs](https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/664)

Comment: I couldn't accept David's suggested edit, so I made a gist out of it: https://gist.github.com/igor47/5997028 ; i haven't had to overcome the issue of nested arrays, but it would definitely be a problem.

Comment: The Chef issue has been resolved. (I'm using version 12.4.1.)

Comment: Hope I am not too late but my answer here could be of help http://stackoverflow.com/a/36292425/160950

Comment: #inject would be preferred to rebuild the hash.

Comment: It is 2021, nobody should use this monkeypatch or any of the other suggested workarounds in this answer.   It just works now.  Looks like it got fixed back in 2015.

Answer (score 4):

I hope I am not too late to the party but merging the node object with an empty hash did it for me:

```
chef (12.6.0)> {}.merge(node).class
 => Hash
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and after much hacking around came up with this:

```
json_string = node[:attr_tree].inspect.gsub(/\=\>/,':')
my_hash = JSON.parse(json_string, {:symbolize_names => true})
```

inspect does the deep parsing that is missing from the other methods proposed and I end up with a hash that I can modify and pass around as needed.

Comment: For a 1-liner, ```JSON.parse(hash.to_json, symbolize_names: true)```. Fairly evil, but much easier to maintain than more complex solutions.

Comment: That fails if you have ruby objects in the node hash.

Answer (score -2):

The above answer is a little unnecessary. You can just do this:

```
json = node[:whatever][:whatever].to_hash.to_json
JSON.parse(json)
```

Comment: this is not true; because `to_hash` is shallow, you'll end up with `ImmutableMash` objects as values. the `to_json` function doesn't know how to handle this kind of object and will barf. that's the whole point of this question.