# ruby/hash:Chef::Node::ImmutableMash included in file when converting Chef attributes to yaml

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, yaml

I am trying to write a `.yml` file from a subset of attributes. Here's the resource definition I'm using:

```
file '/home/user/file.yml' do
  owner 'user'
  group 'user'
  mode '0755'
  content node['default']['properties'].to_yaml
end
```

When I run this, the `file.yml` ends up looking like this though:

```
--- !ruby/hash:Chef::Node::ImmutableMash
config: !ruby/hash:Chef::Node::ImmutableMash
  example: value
  another: value
```

How do I get clean yaml output without all the `!ruby/hash:Chef::Node::ImmutableMash` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out all you need to do is convert the attributes to a hash explicitly before converting to yaml. Here is the working code:

```
file '/home/user/file.yml' do
  owner 'user'
  group 'user'
  mode '0755'
  content node['default']['properties'].to_hash.to_yaml
end
```

> Note: you'll need to be using chef-client 11.10.0 or later, because
>   there used to be a bug with the to_hash method. More info here:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/14782389/1688034